# how to resolve window.open()'s options don't work on Edge

Tags: javascript

I used window.open(url,windowName,"loaction=no") to hide the address in IE
but the option location doesn't work in Edge any more , how can I resolve this.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=window+open+%22location%3Dno%22+edge+site:stackoverflow.com)*** , search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: You may consider [kiosk mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-kiosk-mode)